# How to validate an alphanumeric string with underscore in plsql if loop using regexep_like?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, plsql

My input file name should be always like this : `AB_DataLoad_any number of character without space_any numeric value.csv`

How do I validate this inside a if loop in pl sql?

My naive try is like this :

```
regexp_like('AB_Dataload_xYzsdf_36.csv','^AB_Dataload_[A-Z][a-z]+_[2-9]+')
```

Comment: Your pattern should look like `'^AB_Dataload_[^ ]+_[0-9]+[.]csv$'`.

Comment: @DmitryEgorov: Yeah, or `[.]csv`, updated the comment above. Shouvik, what do you mean by "validate this inside a if loop in pl sql"?

Comment: IF(input filename is valid) THEN do something ELSE return

Comment: Please answer question by posting answers.  Comments are for asking for clarifications.

Comment: I don't have an answer.  But I don't want this question to go unresolved/abandoned because a comment solved the question.  ...all respect, I know you are good.

Comment: _any number of character without space_ Which characters ? Since you used `[A-Z][a-z]` I assume you only want `alphabets`. In that case `[^ ]` will allow more than alphabets.

Comment: @Rahul: Regex is not the only problem I guess.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Right.

Comment: @shouvik: Does my first comment regex fix solves your problem? If not, could you please add more details to your question? Please share all of your current relevant code.

Comment: Can you explain the 'inside an `if` loop' requirement?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew your solution served the purpose. Thank you.

Comment: @Rahul i've changed the regex accordingly. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only needed a regex fix, here is one:

```
'^AB_Dataload_[^ ]+_[0-9]+[.]csv$'
```

The problem was in the `[A-Z][a-z]+_[2-9]+` part of your regex: it matched an uppercase letter (`[A-Z]`) followed with at least 1 lowercase letter (`[a-z]+`), and `[2-9]+` only matched 1 or more digits from the `2-9` range (no `0` and `1` were allowed).

- `^` - start of  a string
- `AB_Dataload_` - a literal `AB_Dataload_` string
- `[^ ]+` - zero or more chars other than spaces (you may also use `\S+` to match any 1+ non-whitespace chars)
- `_`  - an underscore
- `[0-9]+` - 1+ digits
- `[.]`  - a literal dot (or `\.` can be used)
- `csv` - `csv` substring at the
- `$` - end of string